# Show/Hide (Read More) Text Depending on Number of Character Pure CSS

Tags: css, hide, show

I have some code which hideing and showing text depend on tag `<section>`.

One section is shown second is hiding until click show button.

I can't figure out how to make it depending on character number,

for example, first 100 char is shown and when clicked button show it shows rest of the text.

And here is my code

HTML

```
<article>
<input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
<label for="read_more" onclick=""><span>Show</span><span>Hide</span></label>     
<figure>
<img src="HERE MUST BE A IMAGE.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>

<section>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>

<section>
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</b>
</section>

</article>
```

And CSS

```
figure {
    margin: 0 0 1.3rem 0;
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}



body:before, body:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

body:after { clear: both }

p { margin-bottom: 1.3rem }

article {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 1;
}

article:before, article:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

article:after { clear: both }

article figure {
    float: left;
    width: 32.5%;
}

article section:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 62.5%;
}

article section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

section {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3rem;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .65rem;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ figure { width: 100% }

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Here is jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/laicekid/LrDTz/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with pure CSS.

You'd need JavaScript (e.g. jQuery works great for this) to do character counts and then apply CSS based on those rules.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  This may help with the jQuery:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004095/jquery-count-characters.

Comment: ok is it possible somehow to use <p> instead of <section>?
i can't use jquery.

Comment: In your code, sure - you'd just change the `<section>` tags to `<p>` tags, then update the CSS accordingly.  What do you mean you can't use jQuery?

Comment: When i link jquery to head section it going into conflict with slideshow and not loading images. thats why i can't use jquery :(

Comment: You could do straight JavaScript to `getElementById` and then do the `length` of the `innerHTML`...

Comment: YES! i changed <section>  to <p> and now it works cool :) THANK you :)